# Akka. How to scale-up?

Tags: java, scala, akka

What things would need to be done to scale-up (scale horizontally) an application written using Akka? Roughly speaking, for adding a new node in cluster, do I only need to install a JRE on it and run `.jar` file with my Akka-client application?

Comment: Scale-out is horizontally (many nodes), Scale-up is vertically (one big node).

Comment: It sounds like you might be interested in Akka's Cluster feature.  It allows you to add more nodes and contol what actors are deployed to those new nodes very easily.  You can read more about that feature here  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.3/cluster/index.html

Answer (score 5):

While Akka itself scales very well, it can only do so if your application is well-designed to handle scalability.  Simply adding nodes to a cluster may or may not help.

For example, if your Akka application provides a REST API of some sort, how will requests get routed between your nodes?  Where is state stored, if not in Akka itself?  If it's stored in Akka, how to you ensure that subsequent requests from the same client end up on the same node?  If it's stored outside the runtime (e.g., a SQL database), how will you handle blocking behavior?  What if your SQL database then becomes the bottleneck, now what?

Akka offers terrific scalability, I've built several such systems atop its actor model to achieve just that.  However, you can't just throw nodes at the problem and hope that actors fix it.  Scalability is more about rigorous thinking and design than hoping actors are a magic wand.